# Setting the color of a button only working with words

Tags: c#

I am trying to set the color of a button to a user defined color. It works if I hard code a color i.e Color.Blue but not if I'm using the color picker.

This code works

```
buttonColCANSilence.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

This code does nothing

```
String code = (colorDialog1.Color.ToArgb() & 0x00FFFFFF).ToString("X6");
int argb = Int32.Parse(code.Replace("#", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
canSilenceColour = Color.FromArgb(argb);
buttonColCANSilence.BackColor = canSilenceColour;
```

So how can I set the color of the button from a colorDialog using either hex or argb?

Comment: What is "code" in first line of not working code?

Comment: Oh sorry, looks like I missed a line.
String code = (colorDialog1.Color.ToArgb() & 0x00FFFFFF).ToString("X6");

Comment: So `Color.FromArgb` works? but you fail to convert the result of the `ColorDialog`? why not use the `Color` result from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ColourDialog then the way to use it is like so. This will pop up the ColourDialog control and user can choose any colour from the pallete and it will set the background of the target button.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            targetButton.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't use this method because where I'm using the same picked color in a rich text box it doesn't like that, it was only working for plain colors like red, blue, green etc. I'm using both methods where appropriate now.